# Wordpress is trimming leading 0s

Tags: wpdb

I am inserting into the DB in the following manner:

```
// insert the info into the db
     $wpdb->insert( 
        'wp_vkrwps_table', 
        array(
            'zip' => $zip   
        ), 
        array( 
            '%d'

        ) 
    ); // end insert
```

However, leading zeros keep getting trimmed. So if the input value is for example `00501`, I end up getting `501` in the DB table.

Why is this?

Comment: try %s as milo beat me to it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%d` means integer, integers don't have leading zeros. Zip codes aren't numbers in the sense that they quantify something, they're strings that happen to be made up of numbers, so treat them as strings.